# Does naive bayes text classification require real world data

Tags: machine-learning, text-classification, naivebayes

Given that the Bayesian formula is:

```
P(A|B) = (P(B|A) * P(A)) / P(B)
```

Lets say that I want to train a classifier to classify spam/ham. Lets say also, that in the real world, we get about 1% spam. So given a sample input, we would expect about 1% spam.

When I am training my classifier, should I train it with documents that contain only 1% spam, or is it ok to train my classifier with a much larger percentage of spam then I would expect to find in the real world.

I ask this, because if I have a much larger percentage of spam, then the value for

```
P(A)
```

is going to be abnormally large. Will this throw off my classifier, and in this case would it classify some "ham" documents as "spam"?

Answer (score 0):

To train Bayesian estimator, you need to learn PDFs P(X|H) and P(X|S), where X is your current observation and H,S stands for spam/ham class, each one is trained only from examples of its class, i.e, P(X|H) is learned only from ham samples and P(X|S) is learned only from spam samples. To this point is does not matter much if number of spam vs. ham samples reflects reality. However, later on, to have a proper Bayesian estimate you need to estimate the priors P(H) and P(S) and those should capture the proportion of spam/ham in reality.